# Core Data modeler not updating when entity names change

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am having an issue using Core Data modeler. I had an issue where I needed to change the names of entities in the modeler. When I did so, I deleted the associated managed object subclasses, did a clean, then went back the modeler, highlighted the entities with the new names, then generated subclasses using

```
Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass
```

When I did so, the newly generated subclasses still have the original names. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the model editor, you set the class name separately from the entity name. They don't have to be the same. If you only change the entity name name, what you're seeing is normal.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. How do you set the class name? I can't see any place for that. XCode generated the file and classname based on the original entity name, not the new one, and there seems to be no place to fix that.

Comment: AH, solved it by googling a bit more: It's in the "utility area", to the right, where we normally change class names, but it did look a bit different from the one where you change a UIView or UINavigationViewController

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the ENTITY you want to change
2. Select Data Model from right hand top corner as shown below, and change as u want. Entity name and Class no need to be the same.

[image]

3. Finally Clean and Build the project.